# How to edit the javascript sources of a webpage in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So I want to play with the source code of a page. In this particular example it seems like the webpage is an Angular app (that i dont own) with source maps to *.ts files. The main code seems to all be in a bundle.js.

I want to be able to add console.log() statements to this code and learn more about how this webpage works.

I have tried editing the .ts sources (this doesn't work although I expected that). 
I try editing the bundle.js but its so big that it causes my dev tools to crash.

Does anyone know of a VS Code plugin (or something similar) that would let me open the sources locally on my machine, edit them and see the changes reflected on the website.

If not what is the best path forward for being able to edit the local js of this page.

Comment: Chrome Local Overrides sounds like what you might need

Comment: Trying that as well but it also seems to cause the webpage to crash. 

I think it might just be an issue with how huge the generated bundle is.

Comment: If you save for overrides, you could open it in your editor

Comment: i do but after I save the file, the webpage itself become unresponsive

Comment: it usually does once you set the override, but you just reload with the override turned on

Answer (score 0):

Firefox allows you to add log statements into the code when you're using the Debugger/Sources tab. Just right click the line you care about and then choose `Add log`. I believe Chrome allows something similar.